# How to migrate Navision Microsoft Dynamics report to SQL

Tags: sql, navision

I have access to the Navision SQL Server database and the corresponding Microsoft Dynamics NAV interface.

I want to migrate the 'Aged Acc. Receivable DII' report. Once I select the report and go to Tools > Designer I can see the 'DataItem' list, and when I select any of those and press F9 I see the C/AL Editor as per below.

Selecting another 'Data Item' provides another code. My initial question would be, which code from the 'Data Item' refers to the 'Preview' button in the 'Aged Accounts Receivable - IRES' window?

From the code I understand there are 3 tables joined (Customer, Cust_ Ledger Entry and Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry) but I can not manage to output the same result that in the report produced in the interface. I'm guessing this is a generic report. Is there a query that could be used to generate the same output? Or documentation that would explain how the report is created?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Oh man, i don’t know where to start. MS seems to finally buried Navision 5 along with it’s documentation on msdn. But it is still should be possible for you to open local documentation with F1. Just make sure you are pressing it while your input cursor is on the code. This will open developer’s docu. You will not find there any explanations about how data is structured for output, but you will be able to find how things works.

Back to your questions. You need all the code you see in triggers. And might happen you will need code from the layout that you have not yet discovered. Preview and print buttons doing the same except for the global variable `CurrReport.Preview` is set to `true`.

To see if there is any other code open `View-Sections`, select any section and F9. Code will also be different per section.

The form you are asking is called RequestForm, hence the menu called `View-Request page`. F9 on the page and any elements on it.

Also, see the button that is third from the right on toolbar on your screen. That is `Properties`. Many things have properties. For example DataItem’s properties will tell you have child and parent are linked.

If you can open report in the designer then you probably have a developer’s license uploaded to database. Where is the developer then?) It should also allow you to export objects to text file. The you will be able to read every last bit of the code. When window with dataitems is active (for previously mentioned commands as well) press `File-Export` and select text format. Fob will produce binary output, not useful for you.